# Number or *NOMAX value in AS400/DB2 table compilation

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

In AS400, there are some default values at table (QDDSSRC) compilation (Opt 14).
In the attribute Member Size, Aditional parameters:

Wich is the meaning of put a number or *NOMAX value, and if this number is a limit of records or is just a physical size increment.

case 1:
Member size 
     Initial number of records ______ 100000

case 2:
Member size 
     Initial number of records ______ *NOMAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike gave the short answer to this question, so here is the long answer.

This configuration is a holdout from the old days of limited disk space. Some still like to use it though to prevent runaway jobs from filling up their disk. If the disk gets too full, the system shuts down. There are several related configuration parameters, `ALLOCATE` and `REUSEDLT`.

Here is how the `SIZE` attribute works. It has three parts: `initial number of records`, `increment number of records`, and `maximum number of increments`. When a member is added to a physical file (or a source physical file), the `initial number of records` is allocated for that file. Depending on the `ALLOCATE` attribute, it might be physically allocated, or soft allocated. In any case, the file can now hold that many records. For a source file like QDDSSRC this defaults to 10,000 (that would be 10,000 lines of source). If a program wants to write more records, more space is added in increments. The `increment number of records` determines how many records to add to the file. This can happen a specified `maximum number of increments` times. A source file defaults to 499 increments of 1,000 records, so a full source file member defaults to 509,000 records. That is 10,000 + (499 * 1,000). Once a file member is full, any attempt to add a record will cause a message to be placed on the system operators queue requesting permission to increase the file size.

**Note** that this means a file member can hold more than the record capacity number of records, but manual intervention by the system operator is required for this to happen.

DDS tables default this to 10,000 initial records and 3 increments of 1,000 records. SQL tables (those defined using DDL) defaults this to `*NOMAX`. `*NOMAX` means that the maximum number of records in the table is determined by the system. This might be limited by disk space, or an absolute maximum imposed by the database.

**DB Limits As of v7.3**

```
Maximum rows in a member          4,294,967,288
Maximum size of a member          1.7 terabytes
```

One of the reasons SQL can get away with using `*NOMAX` is that it reuses space occupied by deleted records by default. DDS defined files do not do that (unles the user changes the default). So for a DDS table, each write causes another record to be used up. This can cause the file to fill up with deleted records, mandating manual intervention to reclaim that space. The current wisdom is to use `SIZE(*NOMAX)`, `ALLOCATE(*NO)` and `REUSEDLT(*YES)`. This, once and for all, lets the system decide how to allocate disk space. You can get this behavior for DDS defined files by changing the command defaults for `CRTPF`.

Comment: Hi, I have too many misconceptions about this, because i'm newbie in as400 world. when you say records, in source member file, you mean source code that is saved like records in a table?, because all code in as400 is saved in tables = files/members ?, thank you for your help.

Comment: So finally, if im understand in the default example, if i have 10,000 initial records and 3 increments of 1,000 records, i have a maximun size of 13000 records, so if i have 50 lines of source code then i finally have 12950 for data records, rigth?

Comment: No, source is stored in source physical files, data is stored in physical files. A file will contain either data or source. You cannot reference a source physical file with a logical file. There are other differences as well.

Comment: so in this case we are only talk about physical files?, so the 10000 initial records are about source code?, if my source code is just 50 records (lines) i dont need to put *NOMAX?, in other words *NOMAX is about records in columns tables of about source code?.

Comment: A source file is a special multi-member physical file. Source is stored one line per record in a source physical file. All source for one object is stored in a single member of the source physical file. Data is stored in a physical file as well, but not in a source physical file. *NOMAX is about the number of records that can be contained in a single member of a physical file. This is true for both source physical files and data physical files.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Better place for discussion is the midrange mailing list. http://www.midrange.com/#lists

Comment: There is no problem creating either native LFs or SQL VIEWs over source physical files (PFs). Also, although source has historically been stored as records in source PF members, it may be stored in streamfiles just as it might be done on a PC or other platform.

Answer (score 0):

*NOMAX means there is no maximum to the number of records that can be added to each member of the file except that determined by the operating system rather than this parameter value. When set to *NOMAX increments will not occur.